# Get only first two numbers from the numeric value in python.How?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have output from the below code and from that output I need to get only the maj and minor of that value.Is there any way I can get only the first two numbers 1.1 not full value 1.1.73.4

```
  for version in issue["fields"]["fixVersions"]:
    cacheData = json.dumps(version)
    jsonToPython = json.loads(cacheData)
    #lines = jsonToPython.items()
    if jsonToPython['name'][:8] == "Ciagana ":
      matches = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+", jsonToPython['name'])
      print matches[0]
```

Below is the output of the code currently:

```
Retrieving list of issues 
Processing CTPT-2
1.1.73.4
1.1.90.0
Processing CTPT-1
1.5.73.4
```

Below is the desired output

```
Retrieving list of issues 
Processing CTPT-2
1.1
1.1
Processing CTPT-1
1.1
```

Comment: Seems like this at least as simple as extracting the version number from the name in the first place.

Comment: Naively you can change your regex to add a lookahead for a period after the first part: `r"\d+\.\d+(?=\.)"`.

Comment: Change your pattern to `(\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\.\d+`? Split the result on `.` and take the first 2? There are plenty of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way, by modifying your regex pattern to have a look-ahead for another period:

```
text = ['4.4.73.4', '4.4.90.0', '4.5.73.4']

for version in text:
    matches = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+(?=\.)", version)
    print matches[0]

#4.4
#4.4
#4.5
```

The pattern is:

- `\d+\.\d+`: Any number of digits followed by a period followed by any number of digits
- `(?=\.)`: A non-capturing look-ahead for another period

Answer (score 4):

Regex would work, or a simple split:

```
short_version_string = '.'.join(version_string.split('.')[:2])
```

Or this, though it only works in Python 3:

```
major, minor, *_ = version_string.split('.')
```